# Can't move a rectangle in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I can't seem to move a rectangle object in JavaFX. I've placed the rectangle inside of a stackpane, but whenever I change the coordinates of the rectangle, it won't move (even if I change the coordinates of initialization). So,

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(150,150,75,75);
```

will be in the center of the stackpane, as well as

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(2043,136,75,75);
```

Whenever I use

```
rect.setX();
```

The rectangle doesn't move at all. I know I'm missing something really simple, I just can't figure it out. I don't want to use a transition, because my goal is to simply move the rectangle a few pixels in the direction of an arrow key press. So what exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

*Solution*

Use a different container type (e.g. a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html)) if you want to manually specify layout co-ordinates (e.g. the x,y co-ordinates of a Rectangle).

*Background*

A StackPane is a managed layout pane - it controls the layout of the items you place in it (by default centering items in the stack).  So it doesn't matter what co-ordinates you give the Rectangle, when you place it in the StackPane, the layout manager will move your rectangle so that it is in the center of the stack.

JavaFX has two concepts for positioning, one is [layout co-ordinates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty--), the other is [translation deltas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateXProperty--), which are added to the layout co-ordinates.  TranslateTransitions work by modifying translation deltas.  Translation is meant for animations and temporarily moving things around.  Translation is independent of and does not effect layout values, so you could place something in a StackPane and apply a TranslateTransition to it and it would still move, but it would move from the center of the stack, as that is the initial layout position.